# Tab switching causes a little deformation during animation

Tags: slider

I made a simple vertical content slider based on tabs and found optical issue when animating . If you click on different tab, current content slides up and in the same time new one slides down. All contents have same height. The problem is that the height is changing a little bit during the animation (focus on bottom border). I don't really know how to fix it. Is there any way to prevent it?

Here is the complete code:
http://jsfiddle.net/YGY26/8/

JS:

```
var active = 1;
function item(id) {
   if (id !== active) {
      $("#description" + active).slideUp("slow");
      if (active !== id) {
         $("#description" + id).slideDown("slow");
         active = id;
      }
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='slider_box' onclick='item(1);'>
   <h3>Content1</h3>
   <div id='description1' class='slider_content' style='display: block'>
      some content to show
   </div>
</div>

<div class='slider_box' onclick='item(2);'>
   <h3>Content2</h3>
   <div id='description2' class='slider_content'>
      some content to show
   </div>
</div>

<div class='slider_box' onclick='item(3);'>
   <h3>Content3</h3>
   <div id='description3' class='slider_content'>
      some content to show
   </div>
</div>
```

Basic CSS:

```
.slider_box {
   position: relative;
   width: 330px;
}
.slider_box h3 {
   color: white;
   background: black;
}
.slider_content {
   height: 330px;
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: hmmm, sorry, i see no deformations. am i blind? :)

Comment: check bottom border during the animation... it "jumps" a little bit and after animation complete it is alright again